Error Converting FMB Forms to XML in Oracle Form Builder/ Forms2xml file missing in Oracle Installation Folder/Error in Oracle Form Builder 12.2.1.4.0
I’m facing this issue converting Oracle FMB Form to an XML file. It says the following:

Unable to Invoke XML Converter

Tried converting it manually by firstly converting it into .TXT and then into .XML but that still resulted in an erroneous .XML file. The Oracle suite I’m using is set up on a server and everything is configured so messing up with the installation won’t be suitable either.
The Forms2xml program is not in the installation folder.
The requirement is to convert FMB Files to XML. I’ve still not found any XML converter online that supports FMB/T/X Formats.
So, is there any other way to convert them? Anyone got the Forms2xml program? Some people are said that a BatchScript_FMB_XML file can also be used to convert Forms to XML.

As I explained in your other post on the Oracle Forms forum, the utility is not a "standalone" utility and can only be used within the product installation.  Also, the installation needs to be properly configured.  If you do not perform the post install steps the tools will not work correctly.  Also, in the future, regardless of where you post, always include the product version and platform you are using.  For everyone else's benefit, your other post is here: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/error-converting-fmb-forms-to-xml-in-oracle-form-builder-fo-8267
